# How do I properly choose assemblies from referenced NuGet packages?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm using the NuGet.Core library to install a package programmatically; this also automatically installs all the dependencies of the package, but some of these packages are multi-target and contain multiple versions of assemblies for different .NET versions.
How do I pick the correct versions of assemblies from these multi-target packages (i.e. in the same way as it's done when installing NuGet packages manually from within Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the VersionUtility class to find compatible items. This is what NuGet does when installing a NuGet package into a project. You pass the list of all items, such as references in the NuGet package, and the target framework name, such as ".NETFramework, Version=4.0", and the VersionUtility class will return the compatible items.

Some example code taken from NuGet.Core and modified slightly:

```
List<IPackageAssemblyReference> assemblyReferences =
    GetCompatibleItems(package.AssemblyReferences).ToList();

static IEnumerable<T> GetCompatibleItems<T>(FrameworkName targetFramework, IEnumerable<T> items) where T : IFrameworkTargetable
{
        IEnumerable<T> compatibleItems;
        if (VersionUtility.TryGetCompatibleItems(targetFramework, items, out compatibleItems))
        {
                return compatibleItems;
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

Comment: This requires to re-implement quite a big part of version resolution functionality; is there any way just to re-use the same functionality that's used by Visual Studio?

Comment: You can use more of the resolution feature built into NuGet.Core v2. SharpDevelop and MonoDevelop use more of the NuGet.Core resolution feature but it still requires some code to be implemented. You would need to use an InstallPackageWalker to resolve the package operations, then use the PackageManager and ProjectManager, with your own IProjectSystem implementation to update the project.